# Java - why waiting for multiple semaphores doesn't work?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, semaphore

I have some jobs (that are updated and saved concurrently) that I do not want to be saved to the database together, at it results in a optimistic lock exception.

For example:
- we have 10 long-running jobs being processed by 10 different threads
- when a job is done, it is saved to the database with it's result (succeeded or failed)
- there is one heartbeat thread that updates all the jobs that are still being processed and saves them in bulk

I could lock the entire repository when saving either one or but that is performance-wise a bad idea (several different jobs can go to succeeded state at the same time).

My idea was to instead lock the jobs themselves:

```java
public abstract class AbstractJob implements Lockable {

    ***
    private transient final Lock lock;

    protected AbstractJob() {
        lock = new Lock();
    }
    ***

    public Lock lock() {
        return lock.lock();
    }
}
```

The locking is done via a wrapper around my database repository:

```java
public class ThreadSafeStorageProvider implements StorageProvider{

    private final StorageProvider storageProvider;

    public ThreadSafeStorageProvider(StorageProvider storageProvider) {
        this.storageProvider = storageProvider;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public Job save(Job job) {
        try(Lock lock = job.lock()) {
            return storageProvider.save(job);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Job> save(List<Job> jobs) {
        try(MultiLock lock = new MultiLock(jobs)) {
            return storageProvider.save(jobs);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

The lock uses a Semaphore internally to acquire and release the lock.

```java
public class Lock implements AutoCloseable {

    private final Semaphore semaphore;

    public Lock() {
        this.semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
    }

    public Lock lock() {
        semaphore.acquireUninterruptibly();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        unlock();
    }

    public void unlock() {
        semaphore.release();
    }
}
```

And the MultiLock takes a list of Jobs (Locables), locks them, saves all the jobs and releases all the locks again.

```java
public class MultiLock implements Closeable {

    private final Collection<Lock> locks;

    public MultiLock(Lockable... lockables) {
        this(Arrays.asList(lockables));
    }

    public MultiLock(Collection<? extends Lockable> lockables) {
        this.locks = lockables.parallelStream().map(Lockable::lock).collect(toList());
    }

    public void unlock() {
        locks.forEach(Lock::unlock);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        unlock();
    }
}
```

Yet, this all still results in Optimistic lock exceptions...

Things I've tried:

- using a `ReentrantLock` instead of `Semaphore` -> still results in Optimistic lock exceptions
- instead of a `parallelStream()` use a normal `stream()` -> much slower and also still results in Optimistic lock exceptions

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The code above does work...

The problem I had was related to the `List<Job> jobs` argument. As it was not an unmodifiable collection, the collection was altered during the lock and resulted in unexpected exceptions.